# Oracle 11g: Substring between nth & mth occurrance

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle11g, substring

I have to SELECT a substring from a table between nth and mth occurrences of a special character (say -).

For eg: If column data is '**a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h**', **n** is **2** & **m** is **5**, my select statement should return: '**c-d-e**'

I tried various regex combinations but I think '\K' cannot be used.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try using `instr` like this:

```sql
with PARAM as (select 'a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h' as S, 
               '-' as D, 2 as N, 5 as M from dual)
  select substr(substr(S, instr(S, D, 1, N) + 1),
              1, instr(S, D, 1, M - N) - 1) as RANGE
  from PARAM;
```

The `with` statement is just there to make the expression clearer.
`S` is the input string. `D` is the delimiter.

If you *want* to use regular expressions then you might try this:

```
with PARAM as (select 'a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h' as S, 
               '-' as D, 2 as N, 5 as M from dual)
  select -- ^([^D]*D){N}([^D]*(D[^D]*){M-N-1}).*$
    regexp_replace(S, '^([^'||D||']*'||D||'){'||N||'}([^'||D||']*('||D||'[^'||D||']*){'||(M-N-1)||'}).*$', '\2') as RANGE
  from PARAM;
```

The regular expression starts with skipping `N` groups of text and delimiters (`([^D]*D){N}`) and then forms a group `\2` of one text followed by `M-N-1` groups of text and delimiters (`([^D]*(D[^D]*){M-N-1}`).

In the regex approach, delimiters with special meaning in regular expressions have to be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below approach:

Select substr('a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h',instr('a-b-c-d-e-f-g-h','-',1,2)+1,5) as occurence from dual;